# Laravel 5.2 JWT-AUTH Token based authentication

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, jwt

I am writing a RESTFUL API in Laravel 5.2 which will be rolled out to third party users. 
Users will be given an API KEY upon sign up which will be used for authentication when api would be called. I want to use JWT-AUTH for authentication but that seems to be generating a token based on user's email and password. Is it possible that I could use JWT-AUTH for api key authentication?

Comment: You can generate your JWT token based on anything you want. So in short yes, you should consider using JWT for API authentication

Comment: Thanks for your reply and sorry for replying so late. Normally when we subscribe an API it gives us a secret API Key which we use in getting the results from API. API keys are permanent while AWT tokens have an expiry date. How does AWT fits in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. JWT can be used for API authentication. OAuth is the standard for API authentication and authorization, which also use JWT, For more check here : https://auth0.com/blog/using-json-web-tokens-as-api-keys/